# as I add a symbol to a label that has textVariable

Tags: python, text, tkinter, label

```
from tkinter import *
v=Tk()
a=IntVar()
a.set(5)
l=Label(textvariable=a)
l.pack()
```

How I can add the simbol "$" to the label

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you should take a look at the [docs](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm) and discover how `Label`s, the `textvariable` option and the [Tkinter Variable Classes](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/variable.htm) are working since you mixed a few things up.

However, if you just want to display a `$` in the label you should use the Label's `text` option instead of the `textvariable` option:

```
from tkinter import *

v = Tk()
l = Label(text='$')
l.pack()
```

If you want to connect a Tkinter Variable with the Label you could use the textvariable option. However, you mixed those up a bit. To display characters like the `$` you do not need a `IntVar()` but a `StringVar()`. Using the `textvariable` option gives you the possibility to auto update the Label's content if the variable's content (`IntVar()`, `StringVar()`, `DoubleVar()`) changes.

For the sake of completeness using a `StringVar()` to display `$` in the label, which does not seem to make much sense in your case, would be like the following:

```
from tkinter import *

v = Tk()
a = StringVar()
a.set('$')
l = Label(textvariable=a)
l.pack()
```

Comment: Sorry, i need in the label $5, no $

Comment: @RonaldHernández: Do you want to have the `$` kind of static, saying the content would look like `$<int>`? If `$5` is static content you could simply add the `5` in the first of my two snippets. However, if you want to auto-update the label's content you need to write the new contents to the StringVar `a`, maybe after concatenating both parts of the sting (`$` and `5`).

Comment: thanks for your help i concatenating and iuse this:   a.set("$"+str(a.get()))

Comment: You should take care of that possible circular reference of the variable `a`. If I solved your problem please accept my answer in order to mark your question as answered/closed.